# shiftRows in apache poi not working

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inp);

String text="";
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

for (Row row : sheet1) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
        // Do something here
        ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);
        text=extractor.getText();
        System.out.print("text="+text);
    }
}
sheet1.shiftRows(0,sheet1.getLastRowNum(),1);
```

I am not getting the result in my excel sheet after the `shiftrows` is called. the data stays the same. Where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're workbook is only open for reading since it came from an inputstream

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xls");
```

To get the result you would have to write the new workbook object out to a new xsl spreadsheet. Something like...

```
File outWB = new File("workbook2.xls");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outWB);
wb.write(out);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

You could do this to the same file but you would need to `inp.close()` first.

Comment: Does it mean i cant make changes to the existing sheet? If i have to make changes to the existing sheet; do i have to create a new sheet every time?